# Defaut values in ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration

With Spring Boot `@ConfigurationProperties` is there anyway to specify default values ? As in programmatically instead of loading from `application.properties` or `application.yaml`

I tried the following which doesn't seem to have worked.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test.metrics", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MetricsProperties {
    public static final String DEFAULT_MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH = "/test";
    public static final Integer DEFAULT_MANAGEMENT_PORT = xxxx;

    private final Management management = new Management();

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public static class Jmx {
        private boolean enabled = true;
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Data
    public static class Management {
        private String contextPath = DEFAULT_MANAGEMENT_CONTEXT_PATH;
        private Integer port = DEFAULT_MANAGEMENT_PORT;
    }
}
```

I just cant see `contextPath` and `port` being set in this case.

Can't seem to find anything in the Spring documentation either.

Comment: which is the property that you want to specify the default value in your class.? And why are you using static.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with static classes ? I thought this was the type-safety recommendation for `ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: It’d be easier to see what your example is doing if you weren’t using Lombok. Initialising the fields that are exposed as properties (via getters and setters) is the right way to provide defaults.

Comment: how are you testing or making sure that the default values for contextPath and port are not set?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I'm following on that now. Will get back to you.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend doing something like this.

Here you set default value with 5400 in case value is missing

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class SessionConfig {

    @Value("${server.session.timeout:5400}")
    public int defaultMaxInactiveInterval;

}
```

And then you can just autowire the config

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringHttpSession
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "use.redis.session.store", havingValue = "false", matchIfMissing = true)
public class InMemorySessionConfig {

    @Autowired
    private SessionConfig sessionConfig;

    @Bean
    public MapSessionRepository sessionRegistry() {
        MapSessionRepository sessionRepository = new MapSessionRepository();
        sessionRepository.setDefaultMaxInactiveInterval(sessionConfig.defaultMaxInactiveInterval);
        return sessionRepository;
    }

}
```

Comment: I think this could work. I was thinking of a PostConstruct but this is probably a cleaner solution.

Comment: You shouldn’t mix `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties`